# Use a CancellationToken to interrupt nested tasks

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

Here is my scenario: The user clicks a WPF button which initiates an open-ended period for the collection of points on a map. When the user clicks the "finished collecting" button, I want the `CollectPoints()` task to complete.

Here are pieces of my `SegmentRecorder` class:

```
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationToken;     

    public virtual async void RecordSegment(IRoadSegment segment)
    {
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _cancellationToken.Token;

        // await user clicking points on map
        await CollectPoints(token);

        // update the current segment with the collected shape.
        CurrentSegment.Shape = CurrentGeometry as Polyline;
    }

    // collect an arbitrary number of points and build a polyline.
    private async Task CollectPoints(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var points = new List<MapPoint>();
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // wait for a new point.
            var point = await CollectPoint();
            points.Add(point);

            // add point to current polyline
            var polylineBuilder = new PolylineBuilder(points, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
            CurrentGeometry = polylineBuilder.ToGeometry();

            // draw points
            MapService.DrawPoints(CurrentGeometry);
        }
    }

    // collect a point from map click.
    protected override Task<MapPoint> CollectPoint()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MapPoint>();
        EventHandler<IMapClickedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (s, e) =>
        {
            var mapPoint = e.Geometry as MapPoint;
            if (mapPoint != null)
            {
                tcs.SetResult(new MapPoint(mapPoint.X, mapPoint.Y, SpatialReferences.Wgs84));
            }
            MapService.OnMapClicked -= handler;
        };
        MapService.OnMapClicked += handler;

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public void StopSegment(){
        // interrupt the CollectPoints task.
        _cancellationToken.Cancel();
    }
```

Here are the relevant parts of my view model:

```
public SegmentRecorder SegmentRecorder { get; }
public RelayCommand StopSegment { get; }

public ViewModel(){
    StopSegment = new RelayCommand(ExecuteStopSegment);
    SegmentRecorder = new SegmentRecorder();
}

// execute on cancel button click.
public void ExecuteStopSegment(){
    SegmentRecorder.StopSegment();
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on the line `while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)` and click the cancel button, I never get to that point.

Am I using the cancellation token in the correct way here?

Comment: A side note: you shouldn't use `async void` for a method that isn't an event handler.

Comment: You'll need to handle the cancellation inside `CollectPoint` as well, that's probably where it's waiting right now.

Comment: Once the user stops collecting points, they'll need to collect at least one more for the `CollectPoint` task to complete which is pausing the execution of your `while`. Hold the `tcs` outside of `CollectPoint` and complete it or cancel it when the user want to stop collecting, then your while will finish as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CollectPoints` method will return whenever it hits the `while` condition `!token.IsCancellationRequested` the first time after you have called the `Cancel()` method of the `CancellationTokenSource`.

The task won't be cancelled while the code *inside* the `while` loop is still executing.

As @JSteward suggests in his comment, you should cancel or complete the `TaskCompletionSource` in your `StopSegment()` method.

Something like this:

```
public virtual async void RecordSegment(IRoadSegment segment)
{
    _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _cancellationToken.Token;

    // await user clicking points on map
    await CollectPoints(token);

    // update the current segment with the collected shape.
    CurrentSegment.Shape = CurrentGeometry as Polyline;
}

// collect an arbitrary number of points and build a polyline.
private async Task CollectPoints(CancellationToken token)
{
    var points = new List<MapPoint>();
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            // wait for a new point.
            var point = await CollectPoint(token);

            //...
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}

private TaskCompletionSource<MapPoint> tcs;
protected override Task<MapPoint> CollectPoint()
{
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MapPoint>();
    //...
    return tcs.Task;
}

public void StopSegment()
{
    // interrupt the CollectPoints task.
    _cancellationToken.Cancel();
    tcs.SetCanceled();
}
```

Comment: My solution was extremely similar to this, only I also had create a new `Task` and pass my token into `CollectPoint` as so: `var point = await Task.Run(CollectPoint(token), token);`